# Search query using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search

Need help on how to **filter search results in the search form using PHP and Mysql**.

The form contains six fields Product is textbox, Category is drop down select item, Business in text box user enters and state, city are drop down select item and Landmark is textbox the user enters.

Product or Category or Business is mandatory. So the user may enter any one filed or may fill all the fields.

Now I need to get exact search result based on the input. Please Help me to solve this

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you have those values in a database?

Comment: Yes I have those values in database. I tried something like this      SELECT * FROM `sign_up` WHERE ( Product Like '%$val_1%' && category ='$val_2' AND Business Like '%$val_3%' and State = '$val_4' and City ='$var5' and Landmark Like '%$val_6') or ( Product Like '%$val_1%' && category ='$val_2' AND Business Like '%$val_3%' and State = '$val_4' and City ='$var5') OR (Product Like '%$val_1%' && category ='$val_2' AND Business Like '%$val_3%') OR (Product Like '%$val_1%' && category ='$val_2')OR (category ='$val_2' AND Business Like '%$val_3%')OR (category ='$val_2')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$query = "select * from table_name where 1 ";

if(!empty($_POST['field1']) ) {
   $query .= " AND field1 like '".trim($_POST['field1'])."'";
}
if(!empty($_POST['field2'])) {
   $query .= " AND field2 like '".trim($_POST['field2'])."'";
}
// and so on
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: Careful with SQL Injection...